# Merge 2 dictionary and Remove duplicate and subtract value of keys of duplicate element

Tags: python

I have a 2 text file in which I m storing dictionary values and reading it.
so I m reading file1.txt and storing the value in the counter variable and for file2.txt I m storing the value in the counter1 variable. 
when i m printing counter and counter1 it gives following output.

```
counter= {'laptop': 5, 'chair':6 , 'tv': 3}

counter1= {'laptop': 2, 'chair': 4, 'tv': 4,'plant':2}
```

p=len(counter)
 for z in range (0 ,p):

```
        if (list(counter.values())[v]!=list(counter1.values())[v]):

            print("Objects value on main list %s and Second List %s  "%(list(counter.items())[v],list(counter1.items())[v]))
        else:
             pass
      v=v+1
```

i'd like to return this:

```
[{'laptop': 3}, {'chair': 2}, {'tv': 1}, {'plant': 2}]
```

subtract the value of counter and counter1 and print the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
counter= {'laptop': 5, 'chair':6 , 'tv': 3}
counter1= {'laptop': 2, 'chair': 4, 'tv': 4,'plant':2}
out = []
for key, val in counter.items():
    if key in counter1:
        out.append({key:abs(val-counter1[key])})
    else:
        out.append({key:val})
for key, val in counter1.items():
    if key not in counter:
        out.append({key:val})
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counter= {'laptop': 5, 'chair':6 , 'tv': 3}
counter1= {'laptop': 2, 'chair': 4, 'tv': 4,'plant':2}
out = [{key : abs(counter1[key] - counter[key])} if ((key in counter) and (key in counter1)) else {key : counter[key]} if (key in counter) else {key:counter1[key]} for key in set(counter.keys() + counter1.keys())]
print out
```

It seems like it can be done in 1 line, this should work.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'dict_keys'

Comment: Just copied these lines into my environment and it works.